# Is there a way to count total number of '.txt' files from each directories and sub directories in python?

Tags: python-3.x, glob, os.walk, listdir

I would like to visit every directory, subdirectory and count the number of text files in each directory and subdirectory. I want the sample output as
Expected Output:

C:\Users\DELL1\Desktop\ABC\Folder1 - 3 files 
C:\Users\DELL1\Desktop\DEF - 5 files 
C:\Users\DELL1\Desktop\XYZ - 4 files 
C:\Users\DELL1\Desktop\PQR\Folder2 - 2 files

below is the program I tried (I am a novice programmer)

```
import os
extension = '.txt'
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("."): 
    count = 0  
    for filename in files:    
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            count = count + 1
            print(dirpath)
            print(count)
```

I have tried like this but I am getting output in the form given below. Actually, there are only 3 txt files only in ABC\Folder1. But it is showing output like this. How to rectify my code to get the expected output

Kindly help.

Comment: It looks like you're only walking through the files in ".\ABC\Folder1". Using `os.walk(".")` will only walk through your current directory, so it depends from where you run this code

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). When I was a novice programmer, I always found it useful to draw a flowchart of the process I wanted my program to follow. Translating a flowchart into code is so much easier.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Actually I just posted the small snippet of my code. The problem is I want only the final count of the number of files on each directory. But my code counts every time whenever it sees .txt in a directory. I believe I should remove the line count = count +1 line. If I remove that line, then how will I know the total number of .txt files in each directory. Kindly clarify

Comment: Do you mean it'll print every time it sees a .txt file? Then you should be able to just not print the count after each time you find a file, but instead print the count after you've iterated over all files. In other words, it should work by dedenting the print statement to outside the for loop